# GA4 Purchase Event duplicate

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager

We are running GA4 measurements with GTM embedded in our Shopify store.
It is generally working fine, but the purchase event is occasionally firing in duplicate.
I checked the search report and found several pages with 2 purchase events and 1 display count. (Not all, but only some of them.)

We created a test environment and ran the operation several times, but the same phenomenon did not occur.
I think that GTM is probably sending the purchase event twice, but I have no idea why this is happening.
I have written the js to send the event as window.dataLayer.push and send it only once on the page.

I would appreciate any information you can give me if you are having similar problems or if you have solved the problem.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Having similar issue in Shopify Plus store. Not only purchase, but events view_item , add_to_cart are triggered twice. This view_item marked 34 on screenshot event is [gtag event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t47pU.png) pushed to datalayer automatically  , at the same time event view_item marked 36 is [my datalayer push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAhLE.png)

Tried to investigate why is it pushed automatically and found this push in [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbiEa.png) .Seems these duplicating events are connected with Google Shopping App conversion events because when I compared conversion labels of them in my Google Ads account , they were the same as in [Tag Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41wcy.png) extension and in [Google Ads account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwLul.png) (last picture contains begin_checkout event label, view_item conversion was deleted)

This app is called Feed for Google Shopping if you search in your Shopify admin or also its site is https://gsf.simprosysapps.com/.

Also tried to Deactivate in [this Google shopping app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxeH0.png) Google ads conversion tracking tag but it does not help. Now I am trying to find a way how to turn off these conversion events and get rid of these pushes. Maybe if there will be possibility just to rename them, they will not double in GA4 property.